# How to create a previous row difference based on a columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
year = c("2018","2018","2017","2017", "2016","2016"),
my_month = c(6,7,8,9,4,5), 
val=c(5,9,3,2,1,1))

> my_df
year    my_month val
1 2018        6   5
2 2018        7   9
3 2017        8   3
4 2017        9   2
5 2016        4   1
6 2016        4   1
```

I need a data frame like this:

```
 my_df_2 <- data.frame(
 year = c("2018","2018","2017","2017", "2016","2016"),
 my_month = c(6,7,8,9,4,5), 
 val=c(5,9,3,2,1,1),
 pre_month = c(NA,4,NA,-1,NA,0))

> my_df_2
  year my_month val pre_month
1 2018        6   5        NA
2 2018        7   9         4
3 2017        8   3        NA
4 2017        9   2        -1
5 2016        4   1        NA
6 2016        5   1         0
```

Basically "pre_month" col is created by taking "my_month" row for that particular year and subtracting the value of previous month in "val" column. So far 7-2018 -> 9-5=4 and so on.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using tidyverse.

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  year = c("2018","2018","2017","2017", "2016","2016"),
  my_month = c(6,7,8,9,4,5), 
  val=c(5,9,3,2,1,1))

library(tidyverse)

my_df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  arrange(my_month) %>% 
  mutate(pre_month = c(NA, diff(val))) %>% 
  arrange(desc(year))
```

I changed year to a numeric so it could be sorted sensibly.

Comment: Great...thank you!! What if I have more column than year

Comment: You bet! If multiple columns are used to group the data, just add those to the `group_by` function. E.g. `group_by(year, new_col1, new_col2)` etc.